# Symfony 4.3 Unique Entity between two Entities isn't working

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, unique, symfony4

I'm trying to prevent an user from having the same Magic the gathering card twice in his collection.

Here's my CollectionContent entity. It contains every cards users have in their collection.
It is linked to the Collection Entity and the Cards entity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CollectionContentRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"cards", "fromCollection"},
 *     errorPath="cards",
 *     message="This card already exists in your collection."
 * )
 */
class CollectionContent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cards")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="card_id")
     */
    private $cards;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Collections", inversedBy="collectionContents", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $fromCollection;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCards(): ?cards
    {
        return $this->cards;
    }

    public function setCards(?cards $cards): self
    {
        $this->cards = $cards;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFromCollection(): ?collections
    {
        return $this->fromCollection;
    }

    public function setFromCollection(?collections $fromCollection): self
    {
        $this->fromCollection = $fromCollection;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

However, when it still allows me to have the same card in the same collection more than once.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I have not tried this, but could it be that in your `@UniqueEntity`-annotation you specify the property rather than the table fields? Could you try again with `card_id` & `collection_id` (or what the field in the table is called)? Also, please check the generated schema and maybe add the SQL for creating the table to your question.

Comment: I found the right solution. I simply wasn't using the right syntax.
I deleted the UniqueEntity and remplaced it with :

`@ORM\Table(
 *     uniqueConstraints={ @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="assignment_unique", columns={"cards_id", "from_collection_id"}) }
 * )`

and it worked, and created the unique index linked on both column.
It is rather confusing having to use Table instead of UniqueEntity to do this.